# Do Electric & Magnetic fields always remain uncoupled if $dI/dt = 0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

Imagine current ($I=1A$) flowing from a voltage source ($V$) through a load impedance ($Z$).

What if $V$ and $Z$ are perfectly modulated to maintain constant current ($I=1A$; $dI/dt = 0$), which should make the conditions magnetostatic, which should mean the Electric and Magnetic fields are uncoupled?

Yet wouldn't the time-varying voltage source produce a time-varying charge at the $V+$ terminal?

Producing a time-varying Electric field?

Producing a time-varying Magnetic field?

Therefore Electric & Magnetic fields are no longer uncoupled, even though $dI/dt = 0$?

Thanks :)

Comment: No. Light is a counter example where E and H fields are coupled, but there is no current.

Comment: It comes from combining Maxwells equations for a vacuum into a wave equation. The Feynman Lectures talk about it. https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_20.html

Comment: Thanks that is great!